# Is it time for this site to move out of Beta?

Tags: discussion, beta

- The site meets or exceeds most [Area 51 criteria](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25906/politics), particularly on users and traffic.
- There is a healthy number of [established 20k+ users](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all).
- The site is well-moderated (and very actively so).
- It is now beyond the [unofficial seven-year age threshold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta/).

I think the site should petition for its promotion.

**Edit:**

Comment: Agreed, let's do it.

Comment: I had completely forgotten this was not one of the sites graduated in the Great Graduation Event of 2019. It's certainly in strong shape compared to many of those that were. +1

Comment: Has graduation been unbroken?

Comment: [Highly relevant Meta.SE discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331812/244695)

Comment: A link to the changes when moving out of Beta would be useful. And maybe a summary of the benefits

Comment: @Sjoerd, That's actually linked in *@Machavity's* comment. Did you want me link to it in the question as well?

Comment: @Ouflak Yes please, that would be much clearer. That link is to an answer, which doesn't contain the info as far as I can see. And a descriptive text as link is useful as well, otherwise I still wouldn't know which link to click.

Comment: @Sjoerd It's really just removing the "beta" label for now. Other changes will likely come in the future but they will probably happen on a site-by-site basis (this was kind of a necessary thing with the mass-graduation, because for many of the less-active sites it would be a problem to change things like privilege thresholds, given how long it takes to reach them on sites with few voters).

Comment: @BryanKrause If it's just removing the "Beta" label - which is just a label - then I don't see enough benefit. That's why I asked about the changes and benefits.

Comment: Does leaving "beta" mean that we can actually ask for and get migration paths for close reasons?  It would be great to have options to migrate to Law and History.

Comment: Just FYI, I think our chances of graduation [may have gone down some](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342082/244695)

Comment: @Machavity, I noticed that as well. Bit of a setback.

Comment: We can be glad if Politics [survives this year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342227/168273).

Comment: I thought one aspect of going out-of-beta was related to deomocratic selection of moderators by elections.    Is that right?

Comment: Why did you edit the question? Did I miss an announcement on meta or something?

Comment: Did you just edit this question in order to bump it?

Comment: @JoeW, It seemed appropriate considering the official announcement that's coming.

Comment: @ouflak may I ask where you got that information from? Is it just a theory or was there some sort of official announcement?

Comment: No, it is never appropriate to edit a post just to bump it. Just because you heard there is an announcement coming doesn't make this question any more relevant. Also it seems you are confusing users with your statement as they don't have the same information that you do.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica There was some discussion in the Agora chat yesterday about this and a Moderator confirmed that they had been informed and an official announcement was scheduled for December. They also said there was no restriction on spreading the information just that they had no reason to confirm it before now. Even so I am still confused on the idea that the announcement is coming as it it at least 2 weeks out if not longer.

Comment: At best you should have posted an answer to your question with the information that you obtained in the chat yesterday though it could have also just waited until next month when they announced it officially.