# Can we move out of beta now?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, beta

Note: this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4257/is-it-time-for-this-site-to-move-out-of-beta) because that is tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) while this is tagged [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

#### Here are the reasons why I think we should be graduated:

- Politics stack exchange has plenty of active users, and moderation happens fairly quickly

It has been my expierence (don’t have any data to back this up) that stuff in queues normally get reviewed quite quickly, and that there are plenty of active users watching and moderating content. At least one mod [seems to agree with me](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58556868#58556868) saying:

> I think we have a very active userbase where the queue is well maintained.

And moderators normally know the site pretty well.

- the site is growing

[our number of questions per month appear to be growing](https://data.stackexchange.com/politics/query/1408197/number-of-questions-per-month-between-two-dates#graph) as does our [answers per question](https://data.stackexchange.com/politics/query/1386266/answer-ratio-trend), the only two of the [Area 51 criteria](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25906/politics) that we aren’t marked as “Excellent” in.

- This site isn’t going to crash and burn

We’ve been around for [eight and a half years](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25906/politics) now and have nearly [13 thousand questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions), so this site won’t burn out.

- We have plenty of meta discussion

Meta discussion is *absolutely necessary* for every site, and we have plenty of it. We have close to 1,000 meta questions, and (from my experience, no data to back this up) a quite fast response time to questions on meta as a site in general.

- The beta label doesn’t fit us anymore

The Stack overflow [help center page on the matter](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-beta) defines beta as:

> “Beta” means that the site is still being defined and constructed

This site is already very well defined, with most new [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) questions being either fairly trivial or about fringe cases. I’m still not exactly sure what “constructed” means in this scenario.

- [See this](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1744/questions-day-and-graduation/1745#1745)
- Graduating isn’t a lot of work, so that’s not a problem here

Ever since [design independent graduation happened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september), graduating a site is very little work for the CMs, so that’s not a concern here.

#### If there are any reasons I didn’t mention that people think we should(n’t) be graduated for, feel free to drop them in the answer section.

Comment: It is not necessary. What would it give? Nothing except change in privilege reps boundary.

Comment: @Gary2 Privilege boundaries have not changed when other sites recently graduated from beta. Reassessing how all the elements of beta sites should change when sites become not-beta sites is part of the refinement process I mentioned in my answer. Indeed, the change from beta is mostly cosmetic at this point, until things are revised further. Full-site elections are occurring on the last group of beta sites starting right now after being delayed for a bit. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta

Comment: For the rep boundaries specifically see Catija's comment on this answer/question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331710/401068

Comment: The site is not yet mature. It is being run like an old boy's club.

Comment: The Politics site left beta back in December 2021, along with several other sites on the network. See [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374096/208518) for full details.

Answer (score 5):

The refinement of the graduation process has been [on hiatus for over a year now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344432/401068). I'm not sure whether there has been any more recent public staff comment on this.

It seems unlikely to me that any site will be graduated from beta until some general process is decided on. That said, I agree with you that this site exceeds the standards that have been used to decide on site graduation in the past.

Comment: I completely agree with you. I just decided to do this because I figured it was worth a shot.

Comment: Update: [the hiatus might end soon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367463/new-community-vp-seeks-your-input-what-should-we-be-looking-to-change-and-what/367483#comment1224394_367483)

Comment: Update: [evaluating site lifecycle has been going on for a couple weeks now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370040/community-team-q4-2021-roadmap#comment1239020_370040)

Answer (score -11):

No.

I will keep it short and abridged. I leave the numbers as your homework.

Point 1: The most asked questions is about United States of America or the United Kingdom. If we compare that to Stack Overflow, they do have most asked questions on some particular programming language but the lesser ones aren't bad either. Ours is bad.

Solution: At least 3 questions should be made my community and answered by the community for each country (community wiki would be great). Or rather ask and be answered by self. Please note, I have contributed in this arena much more than many of the ones reading this. I have asked about India, I have asked about Bhutan, and I have asked about Afghanistan. Leaving aside countries, I have asked about traffic, salary, much more. These things are integral to politics.

Point 2: Even when asked simple questions based on other countries not US or UK, the community doubts/questions it and asks for links. Do you ask the same for US, the most used tag here?

Solution: Don't be in a hurry to comment or answer. Ask for research for any question indiscriminately.

Point 3: People close vote immediately bad posts. This might not be there when site moves out of Beta.

---

Some fun facts:

**Not applicable to politics stack exchange**

1. Many people of the US consider US to be the centre of the universe.
2. Many Americans believe that there are three countries in the world- 1. US 2. UK 3. East
3. Many europeans believe that there are four countries: 1. US 2. EU 3. Their own 4. East
4. Many easterns believe they are an ally or a colony of the US or the UK or the France or Russia.

Comment: Point 1 isn't valid as it doesn't matter what the questions are about. Point 2 isn't valid as questions can't be answered if they are not understood. Point 3 isn't valid as closing bad posts is what is expected and they are not forced to change rep permission errors when. they move out of beta. Fun fact it doesn't matter if this site has a focus on certain parts of the world because that is what the user base wants.

Comment: @JoeW I am very politely saying this your knowledge about UK is very low, so you were asking me extensively about Her Majesty's Government recently. A Brit would not have any problem understanding that.

Comment: That was in respect of point 1. In SO, a Java programmer wouldn't argue about Haskell.

Comment: Most people are Americans here, so you guys can answer about US without predefining many things. Point 2.

Comment: What does my knowledge of the UK government have to do with this site being in beta or graduating? The point is that while this site covers politics world wide doesn't mean that all the questions are going to cover that same base but instead be based on who is posting and answering the questions.

Comment: Then with my limited knowledge of I wouldn't be questioning Her Majesty's Government is that of England or that of Ireland, or that of Wales or that of Scotland. A Brit immediately understands it is that of UK.

Comment: You are a good example of my point, saying with my humility. I always respect you though

Comment: Even a mod declined my flag because of lack of knowledge and because there weren't any follow up comments. In SO, people would correct you immediately.

Comment: The same mod closed my question once because he had confusion about commonwealth. I had to flag it to get it reopened. Lack of knowledge of a mod is understandable, everyone lacks something, I consider myself a fool for example, almost immediate response from people world wide is what is lacking here.

Comment: I am a good example because I ask for clarification when I don't understand a question that is being asked? You claim a lack of knowledge but don't seem to want to put in the details that would make sure people understood what is being asked.

Comment: @JoeW Try to do that for a question tagged US. You shall know.

Comment: I have asked for clarification on questions tagged for the US and I generally get them