# We are no longer in beta!

Tags: discussion, beta

### We have graduated from beta!

This site has spent 3298 days in beta, and we are finally graduating! I'm kind of sad they didn't wait for 3333... :P

Here is what will likely change:

- Moderator elections will happen, and any moderators who aren't re-elected will lose their moderator status. Though, this most likely won't happen until [April](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374096/congratulations-to-the-58-sites-that-just-left-beta?cb=1) (scroll to the bottom of the question to see the part where the staff member says that)
- Eventually, once enough resources free up, we <s>will</s> may get a design.
- Once we get a design, the reputation required for privileges will go up **significantly** if the site chooses so.

So,
[image: Brace yourselves, elections is coming.]

Comment: I wouldn't count on a design as there are a lot of sites that have been out of beta for a while now that are still waiting on it. Also I don't think the rep requirements are tied to that or graduating from beta anymore.

Comment: @JoeW part of graduating means a design will come *eventaully*, though, I doubt that that will be within the next half dozen years. Eventually, though, we should get a design :)

Comment: Yes, "eventually" but there are a lot of sites that have had a significant amount of time out of beta with no word of design. As a side note it took over two years for Board and Card Games to get the first election and they still don't have a design.  For reference it happened Aug 1, 2019.

Comment: 1. How come the site was in beta for so long though? 2. "Eventually, once enough resources free up, we will may get a design." <- Can't someone with some design skills draw up a temporary design, which may possibly be improved on later on?

Comment: @einpoklum graduation was paused for a significant amount of time.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica: What, you mean, paused arbitrarily? For years?That sounds... umm, not right.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica From CMs, there's no resources to do designs for any sites for the foreseeable future. But graduation elections and the removal of "beta" is a good step

Comment: @Machavity What if the site itself (on the site meta) comes up with a temporary design and provides all the needed images in the required formats and resolutions? Would SE consider such a community-provided, community-approved design for use or reuse in the foreseeable future? Asking for this site and for Parenting SE. Thx.

Comment: @TimurShtatland the main [meta announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374096) said *"We hope that some sort of design love (or perhaps theme customization) will come in the future, but we don't have concrete details of what this will look like or a timeline of when this will happen."* So such an approach is possible, but not planned in detail. I think the discussion is best suited for main meta as many more sites might be interested in this.

Comment: @JJJ Thank you for the suggestion. Posted the Q on main meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374415/578690

Comment: Hm. You know, despite the fact that I know an awful lot about politics, I really despise politics. But I'm glad this is meaningful to other people; wish I could share in it.

Comment: @TedWrigley I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean when you say when you say "I really despise politics." Could you please clarify that for me? Thanks.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica: Sigh... I love the ideal of politics; I despise the practical reality of it. In Liberal philosophy, politics is meant to balance the (not always rational) desires and interests of people against each other to produce something approaching a rational collective will. In actual practice, politics is dominated by the intransigent, the ignorant, the egotistical, the vindictive: anyone willing to close their ears and open their mouths at full volume. Real politics is a world for arrogant bullies and entitled frat-boys, all playing dress-up as noble characters.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica: Politics could be the most truly human endeavor, but instead it de-evolves into dog-pack psychology. This is as true of small, local, or social politics as it is of the large-scale stuff. The effect has become increasingly obvious over the last couple of decades, but it's not qualitatively *different* than it ever was; people are just more inclined to play the 'incendiary patriot' dress-up game than the 'dedicated community leader' dress-up game.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica: Oh, and Merry Christmas. 

Comment: Glad this [finally happened](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4257/is-it-time-for-this-site-to-move-out-of-beta).

Comment: For the math-impaired, 3298 days is just over 9 years.

Answer (score 5):

Just for future reference, **when** a design will be coming, I just thought about a site logo:

[image: ![enter image description here]

The form should be obvious. Beside the nod to the original SE logo, talking to each other is the main endeavor in politics.

Political opinions have always been metaphorically expressed as colors. We cannot avoid that, so the only solution is to embrace it. At the same time, including transitions between colors is acknowledging the power of weighing those opinions. Using the full color palette is a sign of not being entrenched in a for-and-against dichotomy or restricted to a two-party system.

As a reference for designers, here is the source code to the logo. (image upload does not support vector images.)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="m1 7a2 2 0 0 0 2 2v3l3-3v-2z" fill="#e00000"/>
  <path d="m1 4v2h5a3 3 0 0 1 0.75-2z" fill="#d000e0"/>
  <path d="m3 1a2 2 0 0 0-2 2h9a2 2 0 0 0-2-2z" fill="#02f"/>
  <path d="m7 10a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h1l3 3v-3a2 2 0 0 0 2-2z" fill="#ffd000"/>
  <path d="m7 7v2h8v-2z" fill="#b0c800"/>
  <path d="m9 4a2 2 0 0 0-2 2h8a2 2 0 0 0-2-2z" fill="#00d060"/>
</svg>
```