# Politics Stack Exchange logo

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

Most Stack Exchange websites, such as Academia and English Language, have natty logos. On the other hand, a few, such as Politics and Law, have a boring blue logo with a letter or two on it.

Is it possible to ask developers for a nicer logo for Politics Stack Exchange?

Comment: That is part of a site theme change as part of beta graduation and last I heard those are all on hold.

Comment: Related: https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6578/26455

Comment: Related: [Can communities come up with their own site design? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374415/can-communities-come-up-with-their-own-site-design)

Answer (score -4):

For example, we could use a logo based on the political map of the world:

small:

[image: map1]

medium:

[image: map2]

large:

[image: map3]

**Source:**

[Hemispheres Global View Series World Political Wall Map](https://shop.eastview.com/results/item?SKU=2269791M)